# 表１と表２を比較して、差がある部分がどこなのか表を出力したい。

Tags: r, sh

表１と表２を比較して、Rかshで差がある部分がどこなのかを出力したく存じます。

表1.csv
（10行*300列くらい）

```
1,2,3,4,5,・・・
6,7,8,9,0,
1,2,3,4,5,
6,7,8,9,0,
1,2,3,4,5,
6,7,8,9,0,
.
.
.
```

表2.csv

```
1,2,3,4,5,・・・
6,7,8,9,0,
1,2,3,4,5,
1,7,8,9,0,
1,2,3,4,5,
1,7,8,9,0,
.
.
.
```

比較表.csv

表１と表２を比較して、差があった部分だけ1を立てます。

```
0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,0,
```

Rの場合ですと

Rのスクリプトを起動して

```
#!/bin/bash
r --vanilla --slave < disff.R
```

disff.Rで

```
a <- read.csv("表1.csv")
b <- read.csv("表2.csv")
a - b
```

で引き算はできるのですが、そのあと差分がある部分の抽出方法がわかりません。

Comment: r か sh で回答して欲しい場合には、本文やタイトルにその旨を書いて下さい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rで書く方法を回答します。
data.frame 同士を引き算すれば同じ値のところはゼロになります。

```
df1 <- read.csv("表1.csv", header = FALSE)
df2 <- read.csv("表2.csv", header = FALSE)

df1 - df2
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#> 1  0  0  0  0  0
#> 2  0  0  0  0  0
#> 3  0  0  0  0  0
#> 4  5  0  0  0  0
#> 5  0  0  0  0  0
#> 6  5  0  0  0  0
```

ifelseで値がゼロかゼロでないかで場合分けをすると、以下のように書けます。
こちらでご期待の回答になっているでしょうか？

```
ifelse((df1 - df2) != 0, 1, 0)
#>      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#> [1,]  0  0  0  0  0
#> [2,]  0  0  0  0  0
#> [3,]  0  0  0  0  0
#> [4,]  1  0  0  0  0
#> [5,]  0  0  0  0  0
#> [6,]  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: `header = FALSE`をつけないと、CSVの一行目はヘッダとして扱われてしまうのを忘れていました。修正しました。すみません。

Answer (score 2):

bash で書いてみました(エラーチェックは省いてあります)。

```
#!/bin/bash

data1="$1"
data2="$2"

num=$(head -1 "$data1" | grep -Eo ',' | wc -l)
eval $(eval "
  echo -n 'paste -d, '
  for ((i=1;i<=(num+1);i++))
  do
    echo -n \"
      <(paste -d' '
          <(cut -d, \"${data1}\" -f\$i)
          <(cut -d, \"${data2}\" -f\$i) |
        awk '{print (\\\$1-\\\$2)?1:0}') \"
  done
")
```

これを `cmp_csv.sh` として保存します。実行方法は以下となります。

```
$ ./cmp_csv.sh data1.csv data2.csv
```

前提条件は、

- data1.csv と data2.csv の列数・行数が同じ
- データは全て数値

です。